# Let $a<b<c<d$ and $f$ an integrable function in $[a,d]$. Prove $f$ is integrable in $[b,c]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $a<b<c<d$ and $f$ an integrable function in $[a,d]$. Prove $f$ is integrable in $[b,c]$

I make this:

Let ${{\epsilon}>0} $

$P=\{t_{0},...,t_{n}\}$ a partition of $[a,d]$ and $Q=\{k_{0},...,k_{n}\}$ a partition of $[b,c]$

As $f$ is integrable in $[a,d]$ Then

$ U(F,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon $

If i prove $ U(f,Q)-L(f,Q)<U(F,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon $ then the exercise is finish. But i'm stuck in that inequality. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead let $P$ be the partition of $[a,d]$ and let $Q$ be its [refinement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Refinement_of_partitions) constrained to the interval $[b,c]$. Since $U(f,Q) \subset U(f,P)$, and $L(f,Q) \subset L(f,P)$, we have that:

$$0 \leq U(f,Q) - L(f,Q) \leq U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$$

Comment: Ill delete my hint.  By constrained refinement I assume you mean $b,c$ are added. +1